# Kafka Stream only consume N messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Context:

We are using Kafka Stream to write an application. Generally, we did transformations on messages from one topic to another topic (not using join).

In order to sneaking into output results a little bit before flowing it to destination topics, we want to tweak out a debug mode which allows us only consume certain number of messages (~1000) from source topic. And, messages after Kafka stream should be diverged into Stdout or files instead of destination topic. Thus, no message will produce to Kafka and we can get a sense of what result data looks like.

Questions:

1. Is that possible to let Kafka stream consume only n messages from source topic and close stream?
2. I think KafkaConsumerInterceptor is an option to count on messages. But, I don't know if there is a way to close Kafka stream when we reach a certain number.
3. Another potential idea is do some changes on topology Kafka Stream created. Like, creating a new source node in topology which can only read messages in Topic X from offset A to offset B so that we can manually set.

I was wondering which approach is feasible or if there are other better solutions. Thanks!

Comment: You can use store to check how many messages are process. Once you reach that number of message, your transformer or processor will return empty value.